# Libnetfilter manipulating captured packets

Tags: c, linux, netfilter

I would like to modify packets in transit using `libnetfilter`. I know I can do this by capturing through a netfilter queue and returning, as a verdict, `NF_REPEAT`. This topic was covered in [Packet modification with netfilter queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749423/packet-modification-with-netfilter-queue)

However, one sub-question wasn't answered in any of the responses, and so my question is: does the *mode* in which you set the queue (`NFQNL_COPY_NONE`, `NFQNL_COPY_META`, `NFQNL_COPY_PACKE`T) have anything to do with the capability to manipulate a packet? In other words, does `nfq` see my changes in a completely copied packet, or do I have to set `NFQNL_COPY_NONE`?